# How to use WKhtmltopdf Library without using executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

In ruby on rails project.

I am using **PDFKit** gem for generating pdf reports

```
PDFKit uses wkhtmltopdf executable which is to be installed on the machine .
```

- And next step to give the path of the executable .
- I **dont want  to use the executable file** .because if i use it how to deploy it on server .
- the server will need to install it on its local and give the path.

Is it possible to use only library????

Answer (score 0):

The executable is used to wrap the underlying Qt app, so it's technically possible to wrap the library in a gem (using ffi or some other similar lib) but I never heard anybody doing it.

I'm myself bundling the executable with my Rails app, to ship both at once when I deploy (even on Heroku).

To do the same, you can put the binary file in directory (you can call it `bin`), and configure PDFKit to get the executable where it's at using `PDFKit.configure` in an initializer for instance (you might wanna check the README).